# Google App Engine Entity Manager retrieving old value

Tags: google-app-engine, persistence, google-cloud-endpoints

Using GAE, I am using javax's entity manager (javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory) to generate an instance of the entity manager:

```
private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
```

I retrieve from the datastore using the following code:

```
event = mgr.find(Event.class, id);
```

The problem I have is that if I retrieve the data for the first time, everything goes fine. However, if I go through the "Datastore Viewer" in the GAE dashboard to edit the values manually. The next time I call the data, using the "find" method, the values returned are the old value. I have to manually upload backend again in order to get the new values.

Any idea what is causing this? I would like mgr.find to always call the latest value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The entity is being cached. When you change it through the Datastore Viewer, the entity cached by your backend is not affected.

After you make a change in the Datastore viewer, click on the "Flush Memcache" button.

If this does not help, you may need to change configuration for your caching:

> Level2 Caching is enabled by default. To get the previous default
>   behavior, set the persistence property datanucleus.cache.level2.type
>   to none. (Alternatively include the datanucleus-cache plugin in the
>   classpath, and set the persistence property
>   datanucleus.cache.level2.type to javax.cache to use Memcache for L2
>   caching.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing memcache and then try your query again.Most times the last persisted entity data is what's retrieved until you do this.